# If Else Update Script

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create an If Else Update Script.  This is what I have put together so far:

```
IF (SELECT [FileType1] FROM Document 
                WHERE ([FileType1] like 'E-mail' or [FileType1] like 'outlook'))
    UPDATE Document
    SET    [FilePath]=''
ELSE ((SELECT [FileType1] FROM Document 
                WHERE ([FileType1] not like 'E-mail' or [FileType1] not like 'outlook'))
    UPDATE Document
    SET    [Path]=''
```

What I am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add a tag specifying the database engine you are using.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using a `case` expression. Use `=` instead of `like` to compare the values if they are exact.

```
update Document
set [FilePath]= case when [FileType1] like 'E-mail' or [FileType1] like 'outlook' then '' 
                else [FilePath] end
,[Path] = case when [FileType1] not like 'E-mail' or [FileType1] not like 'outlook' then '' 
                else [Path] end
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with your current logic:

1. The conditional structure is not correct - which is what you believe your issue is currently. You will need two updates with the conditional logic built into each.
2. Your use of the `like` operator doesn't use any wildcards
3. Your logic in the two statements has some overlap, since the opposite of (A or B) is actually (not A and not B)

Here is how you can address all three issues:

```
UPDATE Document
SET [FilePath] = ''
WHERE [FileType1] like '%E-mail%' or [FileType1] like '%outlook%'

UPDATE Document
SET [Path] = ''
WHERE [FileType1] not like '%E-mail%' and [FileType1] not like '%outlook%'
```